# android phonegap plugin's java script call

Tags: json, callback, android-ndk, java-native-interface, phonegap-plugins

i have created an app in android using JNI,NDKand phonegap Plugin fr android.

Here i am calling the java script functions from the java native code using the function `sendJavascript(SendJS);`

and  the `SendJS` is made as follows:

```
SendJS = "javascript:" + SuccessCallBack + "('" + JSONObject.quote(result.toString()) + "')";
```

till now it was working properly as my string `result` was not having a `'` in the result.

but now whn i am getting a `'` in my result and due to which my `sendJavascript(SendJS);` is not working and gives me

`phonegap-1.0.0.js: Line 778 : JSCallback Error: SyntaxError: Parse error`

it's working perfectly fine for `Double Quotes(")` and `\'` is also not working.

so can any one plz help me to get out of this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a silly thing....

replace the `'` with `\\'`thn rest are same as it was.........